# UIButton not showing selected state during CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cabasicanimation, quartz-core

I have a `UIButton` that I am animating depending on the current scroll position of a `UICollectionView` behind it. The animation I am performing is changing the buttons image from one to another.

I am using the following code to perform the animation:

```
let buttonAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "contents")
buttonAnimation.fromValue = UIImage(named: "Search-Button")!.CGImage
buttonAnimation.toValue = UIImage(named: "Search-Button-Reverse")!.CGImage
buttonAnimation.duration = 1.0
self.searchButton.imageView!.layer.speed = 0.0; // Pause the animation
self.searchButton.imageView!.layer.addAnimation(buttonAnimation, forKey: "animateSearchButton")
```

Then I update the state of the animation in `scrollViewDidScroll() {` by setting `self.searchButton.imageView!.layer.timeOffset` depending on the scroll views content offset value `scrollView.contentOffset.y`.

This all works fine and the `UIButton` animates exactly as I want it to, however the selected/highlighted state of the button that normally shows when you push it no longer works. I'm assuming this is because I have kind of paused any animation on the contents of the `UIButton` by setting its `layer.speed = 0.0`, but is there any way around this so it will work?

I did have the idea of having 2 `UIButton's`, one with each image and then animating the opacity of each (fade one out and the other in) rather than animating the image of one `UIButton`, but this seems messy and it also has the issue of not passing touches through the top button to the one behind, even after its opacity is 0.

Anyone have any suggestions? Happy to view solutions in either Objective-C or Swift and will convert it myself if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by using 2 `UIButton's` in the end. The front button has the first image and second button has the second image.

So the animations for the buttons are as follows:

```
let fadeAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
fadeAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
fadeAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
fadeAnimation.duration = 1.0
fadeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
self.searchButton.layer.speed = 0.0; // Pause the animation
self.searchButton.layer.addAnimation(fadeAnimation, forKey: "opacitySearch")
self.profileButton.layer.speed = 0.0; // Pause the animation
self.profileButton.layer.addAnimation(fadeAnimation, forKey: "opacityProfile")

let showAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
showAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
showAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
showAnimation.duration = 1.0
showAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
self.searchButtonReverse.layer.speed = 0.0; // Pause the animation
self.searchButtonReverse.layer.addAnimation(showAnimation, forKey: "opacitySearchReverse")
self.profileButtonReverse.layer.speed = 0.0; // Pause the animation
self.profileButtonReverse.layer.addAnimation(showAnimation, forKey: "opacityProfileReverse")
```

Then as I described in my question I update the state of the animation in `scrollViewDidScroll() {` by setting `self.searchButton.imageView!.layer.timeOffset` depending on the scroll views content offset value `scrollView.contentOffset.y`.

The only issue at this point is that although we are animating the `opacity` value of the first button and it becomes zero at some point, the actual system value **is not** updated, i.e. even if it appears the first button's `opacity` is 0, if you were to print this value out it would still be its initial value (or what it was last set at). This means that although it appears the front button has gone and the back button is now showing, the first button still consumes the touch events and so the back button will never show its selected state/be pressed.

To overcome this I subclassed `UIButton` and `override` the `pointInside()` method that is called when a touch event occurs (you can put the following code below your main class in the same swift file):

```
class HeaderButton : UIButton {
    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        var useFrontButton = super.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)
        if self.layer.timeOffset > 0.5 {
            useFrontButton = false
        }
        return useFrontButton
    }
}
```

Then set the **front button** to be of type `HeaderButton` (the class we just created).

Now each time you press the front button, `pointInside()` is called, and if the front buttons `timeOffset` value is greater than 0.5 (i.e. its `opacity` is less than 0.5), then `false` is returned and the front button will not receive the touch. It will be passed through to the view behind - your back button.

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed the alpha when the button is pressed like this?

```
   if (button.selected) {
        self.button.alpha = 0.5;
    } else {
        self.button.alpha = 1.0;
    }
```

I believe you would change the attributes of the outlet of the button, not the action.

Comment: Where would you put this?